Why does ggplot have margin between y=0 and x-axis?
By default, ggplot2 figures include a small margin between the plot area and the axes such that, for example, the x axis intersects the y axis just below y=0. I know how to remove this. My question is does anyone know why this is done by default? I have been challenged about this with respect to data accessibility and would like to know the justification of this design default. Example below:
library(ggplot2)
x <- y <- seq(0,10,1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x,y)) +theme_bw()


thanks

The documentation for expand (e.g. scale_continuous) notes: "For position scales, a vector of range expansion constants used to add some padding around the data to ensure that they are placed some distance away from the axes."

If you didn't have the expansion, you'd have to draw parts of some geoms outside the panel. You can do that with coord_cartesian(clip = "off), but that isn't always desirable.
compare
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x,y), size = 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw()

to
ggplot() + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x,y), size = 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw()

and
ggplot() + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x,y), size = 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_bw()

